# gradle spring boot webservice return json " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException " no convert

Tags: json, web-services, rest, gradle, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a simple spring boot web service that returns json, but i get this error " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: testSomething " even tho i have the jackson json dependencies in my gradle.build through the spring-boot-starter-web

rest controller.

```
 package controller;

    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
    import com.anders.cphbusiness.numbersModel.testSomething;


    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public class restController {

        public restController() {
        }

        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody testSomething test() {
            return new testSomething("asd", 5);
        }

    }
```

the model.

```
package numbersModel;

public class testSomething {

    private String msg;
    private int aNumber;

    public testSomething(String msg, int aNumber) {
        this.msg = msg;
        this.aNumber = aNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return msg;
    }
}
```

added

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
```

for jackson json support in my gradle.build file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding also:

```
 compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
```

NOTE: Also it is a good practise to start your class name with upper case letter.

```
public class testSomething
```

to

```
public class TestSomething
```